# is ther any more efficient way to make python file by python?

Tags: python

what i want is make directory like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDylt.png)

and i write like this:

```
    app_path = os.getcwd() + "/" + app_name
Path(app_path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
with open("__init__.py", 'w') as f:
    f.write(f"# {app_name} created by user.")
with open("config.py", 'w') as f:
    f.write(f"# write your models here.")
with open("tests.py", 'w') as f:
    f.write(f"# write your {app_name} tests here.")
Path(f"/{app_path}/api").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
with open(f"/{app_path}/api/__init__.py", 'w') as f:
    pass
with open(f"/{app_path}/api/views.py", 'w') as f:
    pass
with open(f"/{app_path}/api/models.py", 'w') as f:
    pass
with open(f"/{app_path}/api/schemas.py", 'w') as f:
    pass
```

any more efficient or pythonic way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pathlib.Path` objects have `touch` and `write_text` methods that would be useful.

```
from pathlib import Path

app_path = Path.cwd() / app_name
app_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
(app_path / "__init__.py").write_text(f"# {app_name} created by user.")
(app_path / "config.py").write_text("# write your models here")
(app_path / "tests.py").write_text(f"# write your {app_name} tests here.")

api_path = app_path / f"{app_name}_api"
api_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
for f in ["__init__", "views", "models", "schemas"]:
     (api_path / f"{f}.py").touch()
```